# kong needs to start after cassandra, but cassandra is slow to actually accept connections so kong fails to start

Tags: rhel, systemd

I am setting up kong as an API gateway.  It requires cassandra.

I am using Centos 7, and I created systemd unit file for each with kong starting after cassandra, and requiring cassandra.

Here are my unit files.

Kong:

```
[Unit]
Description=Kong API Gateway
After=network.target
After=cassandra.service
Requires=cassandra.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/kong start
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/kong stop
ExecReload=/usr/local/bin/kong reload
Type=forking
PIDFile=/usr/local/kong/kong.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Cassandra:

```
[Unit]
Description=Cassandra DB
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/apache-cassandra-2.1.11/bin/cassandra -p /run/cassandra.pid
ExecStop=/usr/bin/kill $(cat /run/cassandra.pid)
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/cassandra.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Kong always fails due to cassandra not accepting connections yet.  Cassandra creates it's pid file, which appears to be what systemd uses to know that it's up, but it doesn't start listening for connections for several seconds.

Is there a good systemd way to make this work?

One of my ideas was to create a separate script for kong that would wait for the cassandra TCP port to be listening before starting.

If cassandra would either not fork until it's actually ready, or not create the pid file until it's actually ready, I think that would fix it.

Comment: You can use an `ExecStartPost=` directive in the `cassandra.service` that will wait until Cassandra is allowing connections.  This will delay the Cassandra "start" event and therefore delay Kong starting.

Comment: Thank you.  That is what I need.  I created a script that runs `lsof -Pi :9042 -sTCP:LISTEN` every one-tenth of a second for up to one hundred iterations (ten seconds), and if it's successful, exits with 0, and after the loop with no success exits 1.  I then set that script to be the value of ExecStartPost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an `ExecStartPost=` directive in the `cassandra.service` that will wait until Cassandra is allowing connections.  This will delay the Cassandra "start" event and therefore delay Kong starting.

@Gregory came up with:

```
ExecStartPost=/bin/bash -c 'for i in `seq 1 100`; do \
        if lsof -Pi :5671 -sTCP:LISTEN &>/dev/null; then \
            exit 0; \
        fi; \
        sleep 0.1; \
    done; \
    exit 1'
```